# How to print raw values in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void print_raw(RawVector x) {

  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    Rcout << x[i] << " ";
  }
  Rcout << std::endl;
}

/*** R
x <- as.raw(0:10)
print(x)
print_raw(x)
*/
```

I would like Rcpp to print values of type "raw" the same way as R does.
Is it possible? With the current code, I get only a blank line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to cast the individual values to `int`<sup>1</sup> first. Furthermore, in order to get the hexadecimal, zero-padded output you need to use [`<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) functions.

Using a range-`for` loop, the conversion can happen implicitly in the initialisation of the loop variable:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void print_raw(RawVector x) {
  for (int v : x) {
    Rcout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << v << ' ';
  }
  Rcout << '\n';
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> from `Rbyte`, [which is a `typedef` for `unsigned char`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0ba66a2bc236ae5b009af910688575aa4adddd2c/src/include/Rinternals.h#L55).

Answer (score 4):

Well the *easiest* solution to print-like-R is to call the (C++) function `print()` as it dispatches to the R function internally:

#### Code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void print_raw(RawVector x) {
  print(x);
}

/*** R
x <- as.raw(0:10)
print(x)
print_raw(x)
*/
```

#### Output:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/so51169994.cpp")

R> x <- as.raw(0:10)

R> print(x)
 [1] 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a

R> print_raw(x)
 [1] 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a
R>
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution. At the end, I would like to print only one element in a larger message thanks to `Rcout`.